# Passing numeric variable from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, variables, integer

I have set up a simple webpage that turns on LEDs for a specific duration depending on which button is pressed.  Each button currently calls a different python file, but other than a couple variables, the scripts are all the same.  I want to pass a variable from PHP to Python3 that tells a single script which light to turn on and for how long.  All of the YouTube videos I have seen passing variables are related to webpages, not robotics.  I can get PHP to pass a word and print that word, but when I try to pass an integer to Python, it gets stuck every time.

The following should turn on the LED connected to GPIO 7 for a duration of 5 seconds, but nothing happens.  If I leave the Pin as a number and only have the duration as a variable, then it comes on, but never goes off, so I know it's running the script.

How do I make Python take the variable as a mathematical number instead of just a word or character?  Thank you.

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_GET['test2']))
{
exec("sudo python /var/www/html/paramtest.py '7' '5'");
echo "test button 2";
}
```

Python code:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)

x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]

GPIO.output(x, True)
sleep(y)
GPIO.output(x, False)
GPIO.cleanup()
print "done"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm not misunderstanding the question, you just need to explicitly cast the string containing your number into an `int` instead.

To do this, you can simply use `int()` like so:

```
x = int(x)
```

If needed you can also specify the base that your input string is in as the second argument, like this:

```
y = int(y,10)
```

if y is a string containing a number in base 10.

You can also refer to the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int) if you need more details on this or other methods.